# Add manual DbSet to Partial class DbContext EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I get an old project where I need to add a new functionnality.
Edmx was generated a while ago and I don't want to edit it or generate it back.
My idea is simply to add a new partial class with my two new DbSet:

```
public partial class MyContextClass
{
    public virtual DbSet<Labels> Labels { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LabelsWeight> LabelsWeights { get; set; }
}
```

My edmx generate the original MyContextClass:

```
public partial class MyContextClass : DbContext
{ .... }
```

Here is my Business object:

```
public class Labels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In DB, I have:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Labels](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Label] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Active] bit NULL,
[Operation] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
[Value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK.Labels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,            
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But I get error:

```
The entity type Labels is not part of the model for the current context.
```

Is it something that I missed ?

Comment: It might be a good idea to switch to code-first (without migrations, and maybe by generating a code-first model from the database to start with). Note that edmx support is stopped in EF7.

Comment: Yes for this project specifically (for Identity part) I did what you said. But here I don't want to use a different context. This kind of thing makes me in loves with code first ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Business object, it can update:

```
public class Labels
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public string Operation { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you use Edmx then it auto generate all base context for you, I don't think it don't work. Maybe you can try to again generate edmx

Answer (score 0):

You should add new entity type **Labels** in model browser window.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HotRh.jpg)

Comment: I tried this but my new tables is not listed in Based Type (new connectionString) and I don't see any refresh list help. If I add without linking on base type I got an error error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - Labels.

Answer (score 0):

So finally, I ended by generate model from database in edmx as in DbFirst, xml in edmx is used:

< EntitySet ....

< EntityType ....

< EntitySetMapping ....

< Association .... (for FK)

So ending is that is not possible to only use partial class to add DbSet ... :(

Answer (score 0):

I use DataContext not DBContext and I always create my data classes like below.

```
 [Table(Name = "AppSettings")]
public class AppSetting
{
    [Column(Name = "Id", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "SettingName")]
    public string SettingName;
    [Column(Name = "SettingValue", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public string SettingValue;


    public AppSetting()
    {
        SettingName = String.Empty;
        SettingValue = String.Empty;
    }

}
```

So alter you class to look like below

```
     [Table(Name = "Labels")]
public class Labels
{
    [Column(Name = "Id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     [Column(Name = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
     [Column(Name = "Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
     [Column(Name = "Active", CanBeNull=true)]
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
     [Column(Name = "Operation")]
    public string Operation { get; set; }
     [Column(Name = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You may have better results

Comment: You would need to use the below ref
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Linq;